# How to overlay two images in C#

Tags: c#, image, overlay

So ive tried following a load of different tutorials on Stack and the internet on how to do this, but i'm getting nowhere.

this is the closest ive gotten:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image image1 = Image.FromFile("S:\\Software\\C#\\Project\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\1.png");
        Image image2 = Image.FromFile("S:\\Software\\C#\\Project\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\2.png");
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image1))
        {
            g.DrawImageUnscaled(image2, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

And when i click my button, it executes the code but literally nothing happens, why is this?

Comment: You are neither saving nor displaying the result, so you aren't seeing it...

Comment: How would i do that? I thought the DrawImageUnscaled was the method to fraw it to the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do something with your image object afterwards. You have at least two possibilities:

Either save it back to a file using the [Image.Save method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah.aspx), e.g.

```
image1.Save("S:\\Test.jpg");
```

or place a PictureBox on your Form and put it in there

```
PictureBox1.Image = image1;
```

...to place it in a new Window:

```
Form imgForm = new Form();
imgForm.BackgroundImage = image1;
imgForm.Show();
```

Comment: is there a way to make it open in a separate window?

Comment: Yes, you could create a new Form object and display it, I'll add it to the answer

Comment: Thanks man, and resizing the window would be as simple as passing size variables in the instantiation of the imgForm object right ?

Comment: Also, how easy would it be to enable things like a right click or copy to clipboard option ?

Comment: Yep, resizing the window is as simple as assigning "imgForm.Size = image1.Size;"

Comment: For right-click menus you need to add the ContextMenuStrip control to your form. If you've got questions regarding the context menu, you should probably ask another question.

Comment: this will load the first image... not the combined one

Comment: my code is not about loading, but about saving - and after combining them, you've got only one image to save